# Android - Fit image in a circle button

Tags: android, xml

#### Main problem:

I want to put my *squared picture* (or any other picture) in a rounded view (as a button).

#### What I tried

- Created a circle drawable and set it as the background of the `ImageView`. Then set my image as src.
- Used [com.github.markushi:circlebutton](https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton)

#### Results:

In both cases, the result is
[image]

I looked a lot on the net and the only solutions I found were the two listed above. I can't really figure out how to crop my Image to fit the central part of my circle.

I am looking for one solution between:

- Image resized in the center of the button (not touching the border)
- Image cut to not go outside circle borders.

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Use android:scaleType="centerInside"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fitting image into circle button you can try following ways:

`android:scaleType="centerInside"`

and the other one is

`android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

inside `ImageView` and you are good to go.

Comment: fitCenter is not working, centerInside is what I was looking for, thanks!